# Forwarding SMB on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, remote-desktop

I am trying to setup a Windows 2000 guest (I know its damned old, but it runs the build environment for an even older project) under Virtualbox on Ubuntu on a colocated server.

I have a NAT network between the guest and the host configured.

I have disabled Netbios over TCP/IP on the client.

Forwarding the guests RDP port (3089) to the host and further (via VPN) to a remote user works.

But forwarding the guests SMB port (445) to the host and further (via VPN) does not. (`net use \\<ipOfHost>\c` can not find the network path.

What can be wrong? 
(I started vboxheadless as root, so it should be able to forward ports <1024)

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually share the server's C: drive as "C"?  If not, that's most likely your problem (based on the `net use \\<ipOfHost>\c` command you've put in your question).

If you're trying to use the admin share, it'd be `net use \\<ipOfHost>\c$`.

Comment: Sure it seems that there is no one listening on port 445 on 'Ubuntu